# Issue with ostream << overloading and compile-time determined function return type

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to overload `operator<<` for ostream for some class. I'm doing this recursively. It reduces to base case by using the same operator on elements of this class, which are of lower order (some templated value). Ultimately order 0 is something it can already work with. The way this works is that `operator()` usually returns new objects (by value) of lower order, except for order 0, then it returns `float&` (by reference). So `operator()` has a compile-time return type that depends on context (for simplicity, say just the order).

```
template <class U, size_t order>
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Tensor<U, order>& tensor)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < tensor.dim[order - 1]; i++) {
        os << tensor(i);
        return os;
    }
}

template <class ...J>
auto operator()(J... j) -> typename Element_Type<order - sizeof...(j)>::value
{ ... }

template <size_t result_order>
struct Element_Type { using value = Tensor<T, result_order>; };
template <>
struct Element_Type<0> { using value = T&; };
```

GCC and Clang (compiling C++17) say invalid operands to binary expression ostream to something something aka `Tensor<float, 1>`. Yet when I use the << operator to print a order 1 tensor (`Tensor<float, 1>`), it works just fine. A bit deeper clang also complains that it expects an lvalue for the 2nd argument. Neither really make sense to me.

Stranger still, if I make `tensor(i)` a temporary variable, it works with some compilers. I feel like this is probably the most important sign for what's wrong. I have not overloaded `operator=`. If I understand it right, it's just making a new object and setting its fields equal to the other. It's exactly the same object, just with a different name, which shouldn't even matter since operator() creates entirely new objects in the first place (unless for order 0). I have many different constructors of course but I don't think that matters, `tensor(i)` and `auto a = tensor(i)` should be functionally identical, no? So the below code works on Apple Clang.

```
template <class U, size_t order>
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Tensor<U, order>& tensor)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < tensor.dim[order - 1]; i++) {
        auto temp = tensor(i);
        os << temp;
        return os;
    }
}
```

Godbolt of the whole class and failure example: https://godbolt.org/z/WrYWYn (line 170). (Class is unfinished, no judging on memory leaks hehe.)

Also, I tried creating a lower order tensor element in the for loop body via a constructor and having it use that, again recursively, just replacing `tensor(i)`. This works fine, but it's functionally identical; in both cases the compiler knows the right type. If one works, why not the other.

Comment: you godbolt link shows compiling code? Please show a [mre] within the question without relying on external links

Comment: Thanks, updated it; uncommented the issue so that the compiler gives the error.

Comment: I'm aware Element_Type specialization like this in a class is non-standard and works in Clang, not in GCC. That's not the issue here as the deduced type itself is correct and works fine elsewhere.

Comment: `operator()` returns a temporary `Tensor` by value. `operator<<` takes its second parameter by non-const reference. Non-const reference can't bind to a temporary. This really has nothing to do with all the template games; those only serve to obfuscate a simple issue.